# Driving in the UK After Brexit

Tags: united-kingdom, driving, brexit

We are driving our spanish car to the uk this summer.  We have insurance for EU wide countries but after BREXIT if we are not in the EU, we are UK NATIONALS, our insurance company wont cover us.  Any ideas? Either temporary cover in the uk for foreign cars ?

Comment: Like so many things with Brexit, nobody knows. It's not clear whether Britain will even leave on 29th March, or if it does, whether it will be a negotiated exit or a chaotic one. I suggest you contact your insurance company again on 30th March and see what they say then.

Comment: I have voted to close this question as "primarily opinion-based" because nobody actually knows what will happen post-Brexit